# Change background-color in svg-imge with text inside it

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Image with some text inside it. On hover the svg changes background color except when hovering over the text inside it.

How can I make the svg-background change when hovering over the text also?

```
<svg class="svg">
    <polygon class="polygon" points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198">
    </polygon>
    <text class="number" x="85" y="115">456</text>
</svg>

.svg {

}
.svg .polygon {
   fill: red;
}
.svg .polygon:hover {
  fill: blue;
}
.svg .number {
  font-size: 19px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/king_s/kcoetje0/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this, you need to add `pointer-events: none;` to your `<text>` tag.

**CSS**

```
.svg .number {
  font-size: 19px;
  pointer-events: none; /* <-- Add This */
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kcoetje0/1/)**

Comment: Thanks alot works like a charm - will accept when i can.

Comment: @user3116167 No problem! Glad to help :)